# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Erro ao conectar php

Tags: php

Estou com esse erro há 2 dias, aqui esta o meu código de conexão:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('fdb17.atspace.me
','users','senha','bd','33:06') or die ("Erro connecting to mySQL server");




        //mysqli_close($dbc);

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tips';
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

dá esse erro

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'fdb17.atspace.me ' (-2) in /srv/disk11/2446146/www/tipsbet365.atspace.cc/index.php on line 54
>   Erro connecting to mySQL server

Comment: Veja a mensagem de erro: *Unknown MySQL server host 'fdb17.atspace.me '*. O PHP não encontrou o servidor de banco de dados. Veja se digitou certo e remova a quebra de linha.

Comment: Tire essa quebra de linha no hostname.

Comment: realmente so foi , uma quebra de linha, voltou ao normal, valeu, muito obrigado, nao consigo colocar o seu como resposta, nao sei pq.